# Not installing dependencies inside npm packages / next js node react

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose, next.js

I ran into a very strange problem. I'm surprised there isn't a solution on the internet.

I install npm packages which have their dependencies inside.

These dependencies do not install themselves.

I am getting a lot of warnings in the console. For example:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'snappy'
Module not found: Can't resolve 'bufferutil'
Module not found: Can't resolve 'mongodb-client-encryption'
Module not found: Can't resolve 'aws4'
```

These dependencies are not required, but they pollute the console a lot!

All of the above are mongoose dependencies

I tried:

```
npm install -g mongoose
npm install mongoose --save
```

no results.

The most terrible! I tried installing these dependencies manually. There are about 10 of them, but I decided to make it.

**EVERY DEPENDENCE INSIDE SOYA DEPENDENCE! They also do not install automatically, and clog the console even more!**

Please help fix this. I wasted a lot of time :(

**I am using next js latest version**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a little bit late but I had this issue and could not find the solution either.

There are few things you could try:

1. Make sure you have npm v7+ because they changed the way dependencies/peerDependencies were installed from < v6
2. May sound obvious but remove your `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and then run `npm i`
3. What worked for me, I had `peerDependencies` in a custom library and version conflicts with another library so I usually run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` but that didn't install all the deps but with `npm --force` it did work.